# How to run a Perl, PHP or Python scripting file through putty

Tags: php, python, perl, serial-port, putty

I need to run a scripting file through Putty. The scripting language I use could be Perl, PHP or Python. I will use the scripting file to open a text file containing a series of AT commands (they are just commands to talk to modems), and send the commands to the modem through the "serial port."  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run PHP via command line and write your code using this library.

https://code.google.com/p/php-serial/

Comment: Thanks, I see I need to use this library to talk to the serial port.  The reason I asked this question was that I had difficulties installing procomm plus in my PC.  Its scripting language has strong power to talk through the com port.  But since I couldn't get it installed right, I was looking for an alternative.  Thank you, Napolux.

Answer (score 2):

A viable option is to create the script on the local machine and execute it from there. If it's a Linux box you're on - it's very likely perl or python are already there. I'm going to assume you are a beginner - so don't feel insulted by all this if it is all very
, very obvious to you.

Run:

```
perl -v
```

or

```
python -v
```

If something pops up... you are probably good to go:

```
vim myscript.pl
```

or

```
vim myscript.py
```

And write your program. If there is no vim then use vi instead.

Then, finally:

```
./myscript.pl
```

or

```
./myscript.py
```

Be careful on vim or vi - if it's your first time using those... it can be a little much. Also, note, you can copy and paste from your clipboard into either - in PuttY right click is paste, so just copy all your code and paste it in - but ALWAYS... verify that the paste was good and got everything.

Comment: you might also need to set the permissions of the file if you want to execute it like that
'chmod 744 myscript.pl'
or run it via perl
'perl myscript.pl'

Comment: Thank you for your help, PinkElephantsOnParade.  :D

Comment: Np - best of luck in your script adventures

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade can you solve this :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997622/python-3-4-3-modules-installation-in-linux-error