# Python 3.4.3 modules installation in linux error

Tags: python, linux, putty, docx

I just installed the python-3.4.3 via putty. I'm very new to Linux and it's operation. I created a script for docx operation in windows and it's working great but my manager wants to host it into the server, so that everyone in my team can use that. My problem is installing the packages into the Linux. Here i uploaded the image that what I'm getting. Please let me know the correct way.

[image]

Comment: Please avoid screen copies, use text.

Comment: What linux distro are you using?

Comment: To correctly install python on the remote machine take a look  here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332658/153195

Comment: Please don't mistake me.. I'm using putty only

Comment: @Moe A I'm using putty in Windows. How could it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Installing on Debian and Ubuntu (Trusty Tahr and newer) for Python 3.x

Run the following commands from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python-dev build-essential 
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo apt-get update
```

Check your pip version :

```
pip --version
```

Comment: Neha  instead of using sudo is there any other way.?